# Azure Analytics Log FunctionAppLogs extract JSON fields into columns

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I would like to extract the JSON fields into columns for Message:

```
FunctionAppLogs
| order by TimeGenerated desc
| where FunctionName == "TelemetryListenerCalculateAlgoPostNewState" 
| where Message has "Telemetry Message"
| where TimeGenerated > datetime(2022-11-25 06:38) and TimeGenerated < datetime(2022-11-25 06:50)
```

[image]

I try adding [ADFPipelineRun query code I found](https://medium.com/version-1/how-do-i-query-json-in-log-analytics-ce289b4b1fb5) to select the columns but I get no results (blank and no errors):

```
FunctionAppLogs
| order by TimeGenerated desc
| where FunctionName == "TelemetryListenerCalculateAlgoPostNewState" 
| where Message has "Telemetry Message"
| where TimeGenerated > datetime(2022-11-25 06:38) and TimeGenerated < datetime(2022-11-25 06:50)
| extend MessageObject=parse_json(Message)
| mv-expand MessageObject
| extend myhumidity=MessageObject.humidity
| project myhumidity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, the problem was that I was sending text along json - notice "Telemetry Message:{...".

I tried [substring](https://www.cloudsma.com/2019/02/log-analytics-substring-trim/) but the result wasn't recognized by Kusto as json. I changed the logs to show json without any text and the final query that worked was:

```
FunctionAppLogs
| order by TimeGenerated desc
| where FunctionName == "TelemetryListenerCalculateAlgoPostNewState" 
| where Message has "telemetryTimeStamp"
| where TimeGenerated > datetime(2022-11-25 14:50) and TimeGenerated < datetime(2022-11-25 15:00)
| extend MessageObject=parse_json(Message)
| extend mxchip_timestamp=MessageObject.telemetryTimeStamp
| extend humidity=MessageObject.humidity
| project TimeGenerated, mxchip_timestamp, humidity
```